Google Workspace Add-On addOns.common.homepageTrigger will not trigger a second time
I have an add-on which utilizes the addOns.common.homepageTrigger function to show a sidebar (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/homepages)
If the user clicks the add-on button in the quick access panel it works just fine, however if they close the sidebar and then click the button in the quick access panel again, a placeholder page appears but nothing else happens:

{
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "serviceId": "drive",
        "version": "v2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://cm234-wgs-1.icognition.cloud/",
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export",
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export",
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Ingress Records",
      "logoUrl": "https://hydrakubernetes.icognition.cloud/images/ingress_icon_black_40.png",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "showSidebar",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "sheets": {},
    "docs": {},
    "slides": {}
  }
}

function showSidebar() {
  var sidebarName = "sidebar";

  if (getRecordUri() !== 0) {
    sidebarName = "existing_record_sidebar";
  }

  var ui =
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(sidebarName).setTitle(
      "Ingress Records",
    );

  getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}


The error Content not available for this message is because of the Class HtmlService in the script, and as per Restrictions:

Google Workspace Add-ons must use card-based interfaces. The HTML/CSS interfaces supported by Editor Add-ons can't be used. Google Workspace Add-ons use a widget-based approach to building user interfaces. This lets the add-on work well on desktop and mobile platforms without requiring you to build an interface for each.

Instead, use Card Service, and this sample script is how you can create the second sidebar from your other Stack Overflow post.
function showSidebar() {
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
      .setTitle("")
      .setSubtitle("All fields are mandatory, unless indicated as optional."))
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().setHeader("Record Type")
      .addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput()
        .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
        .setTitle("")
        .setFieldName("RECORD TYPE")
        .addItem("Option 1", "option_1", false)
        .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("myFunction")))
      .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText("Create record")
        .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("myFunction"))))
    .build();
}

OUTPUT


Is there a way to make the CardService render an external URL as its content? The problem we have is that converting our whole interface over to CardService widgets will be very difficult.
Or, would it even be possible to have a CardService that all it does is trigger our showSidebar() function then closes?

Unfortunately, it's not possible to make the CardService render an external URL as its content. It's designed to display content within the add-on interface, not render external content directly. As a workaround, you can create a button that would direct the user to the desired URL if you'd like to convert the whole interface over to CardService to keep things functional.

As for your last statement, the Card Service has the method setFunctionName(functionName). However, it can only be used on UI elements and would most likely not fit your needs.

Hmm yes I ended up going with the button for now... hopefully one day we can convert everything to CardService but it is quite limiting
